# Starting a "3 page" Single Page Website on the "2nd page" in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

So I've started getting the hang on ReactJS and have built myself a basic Single Page Website (SPW?).

It currently is 1 "page" (really just an area which spans the whole screen) with the ability for the user to scroll down to the second "page" by clicking a button (or just scrolling).

Now what I need to do is give the user the ability to scroll up as well... to another "page".

---

Content Area 1

↑

LANDING AREA (user must be dumped here on initial load of the site)

↓

Content Area 2

---

I hope this makes sense?

---

EDIT: Apologies for the incorrect use of "SPA"... I've since learned the difference between that and a single page website.

Comment: react router's HashRouter can help - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md and https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: so you want to set the initial scroll position of the page, that seems to be all you need. You can set it using `scrollIntoView` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView or other approaches depending on your browser support requirements

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem, to be honest, and I agree with Vladimir that you could have scrolled to the "LANDING AREA" on page load. Check out [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/full/EdxBRX/) to get an idea. It's then specific to React that you can't refer to DOM elements directly and need to use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but that's a different topic.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky thank you, I'll look into that :)

Comment: @rm- thanks for the CodePen! I was concerned there would be a scrolling animation involved but that answers it... :)

Answer (score 0):

A "single page app" doesn't mean you literally have all of the content on one page. You can have different "pages", however loading them won't cause a page refresh because they're not new html pages served up by the server. You should look into React Router if you want people to be able to navigate to different "pages" in your SPA, otherwise you can look into [window scrolling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) so that you can move up and down.

Comment: Ah.. Ok that fills a hole or two in my understanding. Thank you and please excuse the ignorance :P

Answer (score -1):

According to my understanding you are trying to build one page website where each content section you linked with internal page linking & added button for the users to scroll top/bottom. It's not single page application. It's single page website. But, for learning curve it's good to start.

Comment: that should be a comment